# Matrices whose condition number is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values, condition-number

The [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the identity matrix $I$ always equals $1$. Are there any other matrices that have a condition number equal to $1$, but are neither the identity matrix nor $\lambda I$ (for any scalar $\lambda$)?

(because if $A$ is a matrix, then $\mbox{cond}(\lambda A) = \mbox{cond}(A)$)

Answer (score 4):

The $2$-norm condition number (i.e., the ratio of the largest singular value to the smallest singular value) of a unitary matrix is always equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for example random matrix $X_{N\times N}$ has singular values roughly satisfying in reality $$\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma_2,...,=\sigma_N$$
which means that the *condition number* is $1$.

It is the same thing with taking the fourier transform of a **dirac delta function** and result in the frequency domain is **flat**. Similarly when you take the fourier transform of the **white noise** which is random then you also get a **flat** spektrum.

Answer (score 0):

For any orthogonal matrix $O$, the condition number is equal to $1$.

By definition, $O$ satisfies $O^{-1} = O^T$ or $ O^T O = I$.

By definition,
$$
\Vert O \Vert_2 = \sqrt{ \lambda_{\max}(O^T O)} = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(I)}
= \sqrt{1} = 1
$$

Since $O^{-1} = O^T$ is also orthogonal, it is immediate that
$$
\Vert O^{-1} \Vert_2 = 1
$$

Hence, for any orthogonal matrix $O$,
$$
\kappa(O) = \Vert O \Vert_2 \Vert O^{-1} \Vert_2 = 1
$$
showing that the orthogonal matrices are always well-conditioned.